# BigQuery: Query with ARRAY_CONCAT() results in error

Tags: google-bigquery

Suppose the following query (simplified from a more complex query):

```
SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]) as count_to_six;
```

Which results in the array [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Reformulating in the following query (with WITH statement) results in the error 'The argument to ARRAY_CONCAT (or ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG) must be an array type but was STRUCT, ARRAY, ARRAY> at [3:8]'

```
WITH q1 AS
(SELECT ([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]) as count_to_six)
SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT(count_to_six) FROM q1
```

My question is: in the 'WITH AS'-query, how to get the correct query with the same results as in the initial query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using parentheses around a comma-separated list creates a struct, so the WITH clause in your example is creating a struct with three array fields. You could do this instead:

```
WITH q1 AS (
  SELECT [1, 2] AS count_to_six UNION ALL
  SELECT [3, 4] UNION ALL
  SELECT [5, 6]
)
SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(count_to_six)
FROM q1
```

This creates three rows of input in the WITH clause, each of which has an array with two elements, and then concatenates them into a single array. Note that the ordering of the arrays is not guaranteed, though, unless you somehow leverage the ORDER BY clause inside `ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG`.

If you really want to use `ARRAY_CONCAT`, you would need to name each field of the struct and then reference it inside the function call:

```
WITH q1 AS (
  SELECT STRUCT([1, 2] AS x, [3, 4] AS y, [5, 6] AS z) AS count_to_six
)
SELECT
  ARRAY_CONCAT(count_to_six.x, count_to_six.y, count_to_six.z)
FROM q1
```

The order of the elements in the resulting array is well-defined in this case.

Comment: Thanks Elliott. Just to understand for me, would it also be possible to keep 'WITH q1 AS (SELECT ([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]) as count_to_six)' as it is and convert the struct to an array in the SELECT statement outside WITH AS(), so that ARRAY_CONCAT() can be used with the desired result?

Comment: I edited my answer to show that as well. You can't use the WITH clause as-is without imposing names on the struct fields somehow.

Comment: All right. I just tried the query where you named each field of the struct, but this results in an error: Syntax error: Parenthesized expression cannot be parsed as an expression, struct constructor, or subquery at [2:11]

Comment: You need to use the STRUCT keyword, actually, in order to use aliases.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL 
WITH q1 AS (
  SELECT [1, 2] AS arr1, [3, 4] AS arr2, [5, 6] AS arr3
)
SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT(arr1, arr2, arr3) AS count_to_six
FROM q1
```

Another option - more generic, but little bit heavier than first one (but anyway you mentioned it will be a part of `a more complex query`)
I think it most resembles your original expectations

```
#standardSQL 
WITH q1 AS (
  SELECT STRUCT([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]) AS line 
)
SELECT 
  ARRAY(SELECT CAST(item AS INT64) FROM UNNEST(new_line) item) AS count_to_six 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    (SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(SPLIT(arr)) 
      FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(q1), r'\[(.+?)]')) arr
    ) new_line
  FROM q1
)
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail for the useful feedback, works as expected.